# GCC Unfamiliar behavior with memory allocation

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, allocation

I saw that whenever I allocate twice in a row, one after the second,
the gcc allocate the second memory far enough, I assume -  so if I use realloc for the first allocate, it won't have to change its location in memory immediately.

Further to this, I noticed that **exactly 8 bytes before** the second allocation, there is the char '!'.

I assume it's there to inform the gcc whether the first allocation might override the second allocation;

And indeed, everytime I override it manually (as you can see in the picture), something in the memory addresses changes but the '!' remains 8 bytes before the second allocation, and it looks like the GCC provided another extra memory space between the mem allocations.

My question is if that's a familiar behavior?
If so, is there a reference for that?

in the picture,

1. **first print:** using first val1.
2. **second print:** using second val1.
3. **third print:** using third val1. (override the '!' so the second allocation jumps ahead).
4. **fourth print:** I have increased the condition limit in the loop so
   that we can see the second allocation, and as you can see, the '!'
   still there, 8 bytes before the second allocation.

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: On another note, the correct `printf` format specifier to print a (`void *`, cast is needed) pointer is `%p`. Please use it instead. There systems and compilers which still use 32-bit `long` even on 64-bit systems.

Comment: As for the *possible* problem (which is only possible to ***guess*** because it's impossible to see the complete code!), don't go out of bounds of arrays and allocated memory. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Please note that `printf("%ld\n", (long)str1);` should be `printf("%p\n", (void*)str1);`

Answer (score 4):

All your observations come from code with undefined behavior, trying to explore memory before and/or after the allocated block returned by `malloc()`.

The bytes you observe may contain ancillary data for the memory allocator to keep track of allocated chunks and perform the appropriate bookkeeping whenever you free the block or reallocate it.

Instead of guessing from observation, you can try and read the implementation and see how it works. The GNU libc is open source, and so is the Apple Libc and the FreeBSD libc.  Look for the source code for `malloc()` and other allocation functions and read the docs.  The memory allocation packages are well documented.

There are several competing approaches to handling memory allocation, trying to optimize performance while keeping memory fragmentation in check, a classic problem with more than 50 years of efforts trying to come up with the best compromise.